# Unicode error when writing Python Pandas dataframe to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to write a CSV file to a Pandas Dataframe.

This is how I am executing it:

```
df_report.to_csv(temp_csv, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```

I have also tried the following.

```
df_report.to_csv(temp_csv, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', header=False, index=False)
```

The error I am receiving:

> TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'

Is there a way to convert the data type from string to unicode?

Comment: what is `temp_csv`? Is it a variable defined with path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the name of the file in quotes.

```
df_report.to_csv("temp.csv", sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```